# Sylius basic listener not working

Tags: sylius

Just starting with Sylius installed latest version.

Going through docs:

http://docs.sylius.com/en/1.2/customization/menu.html#

Both files  have the exact contents from tutorial

AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
and
AppBundle/Menu/AdminMenuListener.php

and method addAdminMenuItems is not executed (menu is not appearing, i've added simple logs there nothing happens)

I've checked and event sylius.menu.admin.main is dispatched in MainMenuBuilder.

So what can be wrong?
I've cleared cache, not sure what else i can do here.

Answer (score 0):

It the service is added in:

AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml it doesn't work

when added to:

app/config/servicex.yml it started working.